# Java auto generate methods for properties

Tags: java, macros, decorator, auto-generate

I'm working on a project in Java and for each of my properties in a class I have the following methods:

```java
private MyType property;

public MyType getProperty() {
    return this.property == null ? null : this.property.value;
}

public MyType getPropertyElement() {
    if (this.property == null)
        this.property = new MyType();
    return this.property.value;
}

public bool hasProperty() {
    return this.property != null;
}

public void setProperty(MyType property) {
    this.property = property;
}
```

In addition, if `MyType` is a list then there are a method `addProperty` as well.

In python, I cant achieve this functionality by using meta classes or decorating my class.
In C++ I can achieve this behavior using macros. In both cases, I add methods to the class during "class compilation".

In there a mechanism similar to one of them in Java? Is there another pattern to achieve this?

I saw a library named `lombok` which use annotations to generate code. Is it simple to write something like that on my own

Comment: In Python you *cant*?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the approach that Lombok took, is the only possible one in Java for what you want to achieve. And whether it is simple or easy to write something like this on your own depends on your experience with writing Java annotation processors – after you have done that several times, you would surely say that it is easy …

But there are still some limitations on Java annotation processors that makes it a bit more complicated to implement your goal. So first, an annotation processor cannot modify a Java source, not even on the fly (as for Java 8 to Java 11, at least – have not checked newer versions). It can only generate new source files, meaning new classes (or interfaces) that extends/enhances the existing ones.

So the recommendation would be to give Lombok a try whether it comes close enough to your needs before try something on your own …

Answer (score 0):

> Is it simple to write something like that on my own?

No, it is definitely not.

I wouldn't recommend to reinvent a bicycle where a good one already exists.

I also don't understand why you do not want to use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/setup/overview) to get rid of a lot of boilerplate code (getters, setters, constructors, toString(), etc.)

You will only need some corresponding plugin for your IDE and Lombok jar (or dependency).